# Update class object with input bindings

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngmodel

I have a list of inputs which are bound to an object in my component. I want to be able to change the values in the input boxes and have them change in the associated object - currently they are not.

Here are my files:

home.component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  consumerProfile = {
    'firstName': 'Joe',
    'lastName': 'Soap',
    'gender': 'Male',
    'profileCompleteness': 100,
    'profilePicUrl': 'https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/09/15/829444_man_512x512.png',
    'contactInfo': {
      'mobile': '0871234567',
      'landline': '018321234',
      'email': 'email@email.com'
    },
    'dateOfBirth': '01/01/1970',
    'address': {
      'country': 'Ireland',
      'city': 'Dublin',
      'addressTwo': 'AddressTwo',
      'postcode': 'D01 1234',
      'county': 'Dublin',
      'addressThree': 'addressThree',
      'addressOne': 'AddressOne`'
    }
  };

  updateConsumer() {
    console.log('Update Consumer');
    console.log(this.consumerProfile); //Object hasn't been updated despite changes to input fields
  }
}
```

home.component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-info" *ngIf="isAuthorized" (click)="updateConsumer()">Update Consumer</button>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.firstName"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.lastName"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.gender"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.profilePicUrl"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.profileCompleteness"><br><br>

<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.contactInfo.email"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.contactInfo.landline"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.contactInfo.landline"><br><br>

<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.dateOfBirth"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.address.addressOne"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.address.addressTwo"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.address.addressThree"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.address.city"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.address.county"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.address.country"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="profileName" [ngModel]="consumerProfile.address.postcode"><br><br>
```

Comment: `[(ngModel)]` should work no ?

Comment: You need to use two way binding to reflect the changes in your model (`consumerProfile` object). Change `[ngModel]` to `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: Review the documentation https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: Not clear which version of Angular you are using. if AngularJS, try: `ng-model="consumerProfile.firstName">`. Also, make sure that you have defined `$scope.consumerProfile = {firstName:"",lastName:""...}`

Comment: @FDavidov it's definitely not angularJS

Comment: @Ric, I guess you are concluding it is not AngularJS because of the syntax within the HTML, but it could be that the linked library **IS** AngularJS and the PO is using the wrong syntax.

Comment: I doubt this is angularjs, as there are no interfaces like `OnInit` and `OnDestroy`. Also look at the `*ngIf` directive. Not a single sign of angular js in those snippets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using property binding (just square brackets: `[ngModel]`), you are setting one way binding from your model to template. You need to use two way binding to reflect the changes in your model (`consumerProfile` object). To do so, change `[ngModel]` to `[(ngModel)]` (add parens inside square brackets).

From angular docs:

> You often want to both display a data property and update that property when the user makes changes.
>
> On the element side that takes a combination of setting a specific element property and listening for an element change event.
>
> Angular offers a special two-way data binding syntax for this purpose, [(x)]. The [(x)] syntax combines the brackets of property binding, [x], with the parentheses of event binding, (x).

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---